# Default weight matrix for EliminationOrder

Tags: polynomials, groebner-bases

For the computation of elimination ideals via Mathematica's `GroebnerBasis` method, e.g.

```
grob = GroebnerBasis[eqs, {a, b, c, d, e}, {x, y}, MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder];
```

what is the default monomial-ordering weight matrix?  I imagine that the weight matrix for this example is composed of a $2\times 2$ block and a $5\times 5$ block, but I'm not sure what their contents should be.

- I don't think they're both *lex* (the identity weight matrix for each block).
- I don't think they 're both *grevlex* (1s on the upper-triangular entries for each block) either.

Any insight would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not actually a block ordering. `EliminationOrder` constructs the weight matrix as follows. Order variables so that those to be eliminated precede (are to the left of) the ones to retain. Then row 1 is a vector of ones for the elimination variables and zeros for the rest. Row two is a vector of all ones. The remaining rows break ties based on grevlex (for all variables).

Here is pedestrian code I often use for constructing such matrices. The first argument is the number to eliminate, the second is the total variable count. An auxiliary function creates a matrix suitable for the grevlex term order.

```
drlMatrix[n_] := 
 Prepend[Table[-KroneckerDelta[j + k - (n + 1)], {j, n - 1}, {k, n}], 
  Table[1, {n}]]

elimMatrix[n1_, n2_] := 
 Module[{row1, rest}, row1 = Join[Table[1, {n1}], Table[0, {n2 - n1}]];
  rest = drlMatrix[n2];
  rest = Drop[rest, {-n1}];
  Prepend[rest, row1]]
```

Example: weight matrix to eliminate three variables from a total of seven.

```
In[105]:= elimMatrix[3, 7]

(* Out[105]= {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
In[82]:= elimMatrix[3, 7]
```

Here is the slightly incorrect one I had previously created, before the mistake was caught.

```
(* Out[82]= {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
  0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```

I think I have been using the "wrong" variant for 15 years in some work, and never noticed. They both give valid elimination orders so it's not a huge issue. But still...

Comment: Thank you for this. Executing 
`sys = {-a d - a b c x - a b e y, a b c x - e x - 2 d x^2, 
   2 x^2 - c y - a b e y, a*x + b*y^2};
g1 = GroebnerBasis[sys, {a, b, c, d, e}, {x, y}, 
   MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder];
g2 = GroebnerBasis[sys, {a, b, c, d, e}, {x, y}, 
   MonomialOrder -> elimMatrix[2, 7]];`
results in distinct bases, i.e. g1 != g2. Should I interpret this as Mathematica using a slightly different matrix than your solution, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Good catch. You could interpret it as me falling on my face (thud; ouch). I had a mistake in that matrix and I will edit to fix it.