# Finding Dual Plane Curve Using Eliminate

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

I want to find the dual curve of the projective plane curve 
    $$F(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)x+t(x^3+y^3+z^3)=0$$
where $[x,y,z]$ is homogeneous coordinate in proejective 2-space $\mathbb P^2$. The dual curve is the common algebraic equation $G(u,v,w)=0$ under the constraint $F(x,y,z)=0$, where
    $$
\begin{cases}
u=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=2x^2+(x^2+y^2+z^2)+3tx^2,\\
v=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=2xy++3ty^2,\\
w=\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=2xz++3tz^2.
\end{cases}
$$

So we need to eliminate variables $x,y,z$ and find algebraic relation between $u,v,w$. 
I feed the following into Mathematica:

```
    Eliminate[{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) x + t (x^3 + y^3 + z^3) == 0, 
    u == 2 x^2 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + 3 tx^2, v == 2 xy + 3 ty^2, 
    w == 2 xz + 3 tz^2}, {x, y, z}];
```

But the output is

```
    v == 3 ty^2 + 2 xy && w == 3 tz^2 + 2 xz;
```

Note that they are exactly the same as the last two equations from the input, so Mathematica doesn't solve at all! I don't understand why it doesn't eliminate variables $x,y,z$ as instructed. [In this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196447/dual-curve-of-the-lemniscate-of-bernoulli), OP find the dual curve successfully using `Eliminate` with exactly the same as mine, what's wrong with my method?

Comment: Syntax. For example, `ty` is not the same as `t y` or `t*y`.

Comment: It's fast if you give the parameter `t` a numeric value and extremely slow otherwise.

Comment: The result of `expr = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) x + t (x^3 + y^3 + z^3); GroebnerBasis[{expr == 0, u == D[expr, x], v == D[expr, y], w == D[expr, z]}, {u, v, w}, {t, x}]` gives some indication of why `Eliminate[]` is having a spot of trouble.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks for the comment, it takes Mathematica less than a second to solve by setting $t=1$, but for the equation (corrected according to Daniel's comment) with parameter $t$, Mathematica is still running (since 3 hours ago). For some reason, I still need to calculate the dual curve with parameter $t$. Do you know a more efficient way to solve it?

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for your comment. I learned how to use ```GroebnerBasis``` from it. Are you trying to say the Grobner basis algorithm is more efficient than the algorithm behand ```Eliminate```? (By the way, I think ```GroebnerBasis[{expr == 0, u == D[expr, x], v == D[expr, y], w == D[expr, z]}, {u, v, w, t}, {x, y, z}]``` is the dual curve that I want.)

Comment: I've often found that just using `GroebnerBasis[]` directly for eliminating variables is often more efficient than struggling with `Eliminate[]` if the algebraic expressions are sufficiently elaborate. But `Eliminate[]` does have a more convenient interface, so it's often a thing to try first.

Comment: To answer a question, yes, `GroebnerBasis` is more efficient than `Eliminate`. And GB can be made quite fast for this example if properly motivated. Try `gb = GroebnerBasis[{expr, u - D[expr, x], v - D[expr, y], w - D[expr, z]}, {u, v, w, t}, {x, y, z}, MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]` to see what I mean.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for pointing that out! It takes Mathematica less than a second to return the answer. Is ```MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder``` something always worthy to try with when applying ```GroebnerBasis```?

Comment: It's useful "only" when doing elimination. There are exceptions, but they are infrequent. For such cases I usually use the weight matrix indicated [in this MSE post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184706/51)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the coefficients of the $u^pv^qw^r$ monomials of the `dual` will be polynomials in `t`, we can use `FindSequenceFunction[]` on the results for numeric values for `t` to deduce the coefficients.  One could also use `InterpolatingPolynomial[]`.

```
FF = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) x + t (x^3 + y^3 + z^3);

vars = {x, y, z};
newvars = {u, v, w};

ClearAll[cc, gb];
(* memoization is helpful when testing & recomputing *)
mem : gb[t0_] := mem = Block[{t = t0},
    Last@CoefficientArrays[
      First@
       GroebnerBasis[Flatten@{FF, D[FF, {vars}] - newvars}, newvars, 
        vars],
      newvars]
    ];
cc[t0_] := gb[t0]["NonzeroValues"];

coeffseq = Transpose@Table[
    cc[t],
    {t, 25}];

coeff = FindSequenceFunction[#/First@coeffseq, t] & /@ coeffseq

dual = Nest[
  #.newvars &,
  SparseArray@Thread[gb[1]["NonzeroPositions"] -> coeff],
  6]
```

Comment: Sometime I'll have time to say something about how lucky I was with this approach (e.g. none of the coefficients vanish for t = 1, 2,..., 25, and the first coefficient being a constant  and so can be normalized to `1`).

Comment: Dear @MichaelE2, thanks for your nice answer.  I tried ```GroebnerBasis[{FF == 0, u == D[FF, x], v == D[FF, y], w == D[FF, z]}, {u, v, w, t}, {x,y,z}]``` and it returned (within 5 min) a single polynomial which is homogeneous in $u,v,w$ of degree $6$ with coefficients polynomials in $t$. I think that is the dual curve I want. Due to my limited knowledge on Mathematica, I don't fully understand your code, but I feel like you are finding the dual curve for a given sequence of values of $t$, which is more useful in the case when Grobner basis with parameter $t$ is hard to find. Is that right?

Comment: @AGlearner You're welcome and right. For numeric `t`, `GroebnerBasis` returns a polynomial of the form $\sum c_{pqr}(t) u^pv^qw^r$ where $p+q+r=6$ and the numbers $c_{pqr}(t)$ should be polynomial functions of $t$. `CoefficientArrays` return the coefficients $c_{pqr}(t)$ as a graded list of `SparseArray` tensors; many of the entries are zero. The function for the sequence $c(t)$, $t=1,2,\dots$ can be found by `FindSequenceFunction` or `InterpolatingPolynomial` if you give them enough terms. (The `Coefficient*`family of functions are good for dealing with polynomials.)